# How to build runnable JAR using Javalite framework as standalone http?

Tags: jar, javalite

As questioned, how to build runnable JAR using Javalite framework? 
Javalite doesn't have known entry point / main class. I browse some of the examples but not found any clue.

This jar will run as stand-alone on server using java -jar command.

Below snippet of my plugin on pom.xml file

Packaging

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.javalite</groupId>
<artifactId>activeweb-simple</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>ActiveWeb Example WebApp</name>
```

Plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <!-- Jar file entry point -->
                <mainClass>com.company.Application</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And the Application.java,

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String webappDirLocation = "src/main/webapp/";
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();

        String webPort = System.getenv("PORT");
        if(webPort == null || webPort.isEmpty()) {
            webPort = "8081";
        }

        tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(webPort));

        StandardContext ctx = (StandardContext) tomcat.addWebapp("/", new File(webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("configuring app with basedir: " + new File("./" + webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());

        File additionWebInfClasses = new File("target/classes");
        WebResourceRoot resources = new StandardRoot(ctx);
        resources.addPreResources(new DirResourceSet(resources, "/WEB-INF/classes",
            additionWebInfClasses.getAbsolutePath(), "/"));
        ctx.setResources(resources);

        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }
}
```

Note : I'm currently using tomcat as embedded http-server to enable the JAR file run as stand-alone. But, Javalite ActiveWeb probably has a way for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can build any number of different types of JavaLite projects, such as standalone that use some features: JavaLite HTTP, ActiveJDBC, JavaLite Async, etc. In addition, if you want to build a web application,  you also will need ActiveWeb.

Here is a list of examples from the JavaLite repo:

ActiveJDBC:

- https://github.com/javalite/standalone-example
- https://github.com/javalite/simple-example
- https://github.com/javalite/ant-example
- https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc-gradle
- https://github.com/javalite/multiple-db-example

ActiveWeb:

- https://github.com/javalite/activeweb-simple
- https://github.com/javalite/kitchensink
- https://github.com/javalite/activeweb-secure
- https://github.com/javalite/activeweb-bootstrap
- https://github.com/javalite/activeweb-lessc

Every example app has a README file you can read to see what the example is for.

In order to start any project, just clone a repo, get it running then start modifying it to your liking.

Additionally, pay attention to the Releases page http://javalite.io/releases  and keep your dependencies up to date.

Comment: You can see web

Comment: You can see web.xml in any activeweb  project. Find a filter there.